# how to ensure responsiveness in wp themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm creating my custom theme from a static page I created. CSS seems to work on a static page but when I tried to convert it into a wp theme, it didn't work. I suspected it was because of how I enqueue css and js.

```
function wpdocs_abrett_scripts() {       
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style( 'abrett2',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/dist/fullpage.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'abrett3',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/examples.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'abrett1',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/css/abrett.css', array(), null, 'all' );    
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fullpage', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/fullpage.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fullpagecustomscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/examples.js', array('jquery','fullpage'), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_abrett_scripts' );
```

I'm wondering though that almost all styles worked except the image being responsive.

Here's the static page:

http://eightelms.co.uk/stat/

And here's the wp theme version.

http://eightelms.co.uk/

If you try to change the window size, the static page seems to resize with the window but not the wp version. And if you try to inspect the styles and elements using developer options, they have identical css being loaded. So, my question is how to ensure that the css will work on both version especial on wp theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In http://www.eightelms.co.uk/wp-content/themes/abrett/examples.css(12) remove:

`min-width: 1167px;`

in body class selector.